# NetBeans doesn't open project

Tags: netbeans

When I go to "Open Project" select the project's folder, and click Open Project, it does nothing! I reinstalled NetBeans but still nothing. Also I know that on other people's computer NetBeans can open the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the jdk-9 files